# Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

Не могу понять, почему так происходит. Если я рандомно генерирую места в массиве parkingPlaces (закоментированный код) и, следовательно, в методе getPlacesFromDb не копирую полученный из firebase массив в массив parkingPlace, то все работает. Как только я делаю так, как в приведенном ниже коде, то получаю ошибку Cannot read property 'status' of undefined. Сначала я подумал, что не успевают данные с firebase подгрузиться и поэтому выдает ошибку, т.к. массив пустой. Поставил async, await. И ошибка та же. В чем может быть проблема?

```
async created() {
/*     for (let i = 1; i <= 65; i++) {
  let place = {
    id: i,
    status: Math.random() >= 0.5,
  }
  // Добавить
  this.parkingPlaces.push(place)
} */
await this.getPlacesFromDb()
},

data() {
return {
  name: '',
  phone: '',
  bookingDialog: false,
  placeNumber: null,
  bookingValid: false,
  parkingPlaces: [],
  receivedPlaces: [],
}
},
methods: {
getStatus(id) {
  const sta = this.parkingPlaces[id - 1].status ? 'busy' : 'free'
  //console.log("Парковка № ", id, " состояние: ", sta)
  return sta
},
bookingPlace(id) {
  console.log('Booking place ', id)
  if (!this.parkingPlaces[id - 1].status) {
    this.placeNumber = id
    this.bookingDialog = true
  }
},
changePlaceStatus(id) {
  this.parkingPlaces[this.placeNumber - 1].status = true
  let formData = {
    name: this.name,
    phone: this.phone,
    id: this.placeNumber,
  }
  console.log(formData)

  // Reset
  this.bookingDialog = false
  this.placeNumber = null
  this.name = ''
  this.phone = ''
},
getPlacesFromDb() {
  let getPlaces = this.$fireDb.ref()
  const receivedPlacesArray = []

  getPlaces.on(
    'value',
    function (snapshot) {
      const receivedPlaces = snapshot.val()
      receivedPlaces.forEach((el) => {
        let item = {
          id: el.id,
          status: el.status,
        }
        receivedPlacesArray.push(item)
      })
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + error.code)
    }
  )
  this.parkingPlaces = [...receivedPlacesArray]
},
 },
 async mounted() {
   await this.getPlacesFromDb()
 },
```

Comment: 1. Хорошо бы в снипет оформить, чтобы понять проблему. 2. Зачем вы `mounted` и в `created` вызываете `getPlacesFromDb`? Почему бы не в одном месте. Например в `mounted`.

Comment: Получилось очень интересно. @doox911. Когда я в created вызываю рандомную генерацию, та работает, в mounted она не работает. И когда я переношу в created вызов getPlacesFromDb, то все начинает работать. Однако при перезагрузке снова выдает ошибку...

Comment: @doox911 я добавил v-if к рендеру, ошибка ушла. Но ошибка того, что при перезагрузке в сreated ничего не приходит осталась. Т.е. метод getPlacesFromDb ничего по-видимому не присылает

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка первая: `await` перед `getPlacesFromDb()` ничего не даст, поскольку `getPlacesFromDb()` не является асинхронным методом и не возвращает `Promise`.

Ошибка вторая: хуки `created` и `mounted` вызываются в момент создания и монтирования, однако сам компонент не будет ждать завершения обработки хуков! Поэтому если `getPlacesFromDb()` занимает продолжительное время, то хоть синхронно, хоть асинхронно пиши, но если остальные методы не могут обработать отсутствие данных, то будут вылетать ошибки.

Ошибка третья:

```
getPlacesFromDb() {
  let getPlaces = this.$fireDb.ref()
  const receivedPlacesArray = []     // 1) Объявили массив

  getPlaces.on(                      // 2) Подписались на событие
    'value',
    function (snapshot) {
      const receivedPlaces = snapshot.val()
      receivedPlaces.forEach((el) => {
        let item = {
          id: el.id,
          status: el.status,
        }
        receivedPlacesArray.push(item)
      })
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + error.code)
    }
  )

  // 3) ОШИБКА! Не факт, что данные уже пришли.
  // Возможно тут копируется пустой массив.
  this.parkingPlaces = [...receivedPlacesArray] 
}
```

Третья ошибка в том, что результат никто не ждёт. Здесь у нас гонка, которой быть не должно.

> Если я рандомно генерирую места в массиве parkingPlaces (закоментированный код) и, следовательно, в методе getPlacesFromDb не копирую полученный из firebase массив в массив parkingPlace, то все работает.

Это происходит потому, что в случае генерации у тебя массив наполняется шестидесяти пятью объектами и мы это видим. А в случае с применением `getPlacesFromDb()` массив, похоже, оказывается пустым.

Вообще сложно отладить код с гонками, не имея его весь у себя на компьютере. Надеюсь я смог помочь.